# Scipy Sparse Matrix built with non-int64 (indptr, indices) for dot

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is it ok to use uint32 type for indptr and indices when I manually construct a scipy.sparse.csr_matrix? Will the dot method of the matrix return the correct answer?

The following example seems to be ok... Not sure if that is officially ok.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as spsp
x = np.random.choice([0,1],size=(1000,1000), replace=True, p=[0.9,0.1])
x = x.astype(np.uint8)

x_csr = spsp.csr_matrix(x)
x_csr.indptr = x_csr.indptr.astype(np.uint32)
x_csr.indices = x_csr.indices.astype(np.uint32)

x_csr_selfdot = x_csr.dot(x_csr.T)
x_selfdot = x.dot(x.T)

print(np.sum(x_selfdot != x_csr_selfdot))
```

The x_csr.data is an array of 1. Scipy doesn't let me to use a single number to replace the whole x_csr.data array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what you goal is.  What you are doing works (sort of)

```
In [237]: X=x_csr.dot(x_csr.T)

In [238]: np.allclose(X.A,x.dot(x.T))
Out[238]: True
```

That is, the multiplication with the modified `x_csr` works.

But note that any manipulation of `x_csr` that makes a new sparse matrix reverts back to `int32` for the indices

```
In [240]: x_csr.indptr
Out[240]: array([    0,   112,   216, ..., 99652, 99751, 99853], dtype=uint32)

In [241]: x_csr.T.indptr
Out[241]: array([    0,   112,   216, ..., 99652, 99751, 99853], dtype=int32)

In [242]: X.indptr
Out[242]: array([     0,   1000,   2000, ..., 997962, 998962, 999962], dtype=int32)

In [260]: x_csr[:].indptr
Out[260]: array([    0,   112,   216, ..., 99652, 99751, 99853], dtype=int32)
```

The dtype for the `.data` is preserved, but when creating a new matrix, `sparse` makes its own `indptr` and `indices` arrays.  It doesn't try to make a view of the originals.

And yes, the `data` attribute has to have a value for each nonzero element of the matrix.  So `data` has the same size as `indices`. In `coo` format, `row` and `col` also match `data`.

Also `print(x_csr)` gives an error when it does `x_csr.tocoo()`:

```
--> 931         _sparsetools.expandptr(major_dim,self.indptr,major_indices)
ValueError: Output dtype not compatible with inputs.
```

In general, don't try to play with the `indices` and `indptr` of `csr` matrix.  Let the `sparse` code take care of those.

=====================

`x_csr.dot` is performed by `x_csr.__mul__`, which when `other` is sparse is done by `x_csr._mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)`.  This uses `sparse.sputils.get_index_dtype` to determine the `dtype` for the indexes of the returned value.  It choose between `Suitable index data type (int32 or int64)`.

It also converts all inputs to this dtype

```
np.asarray(self.indptr, dtype=idx_dtype),
```

So your attempt to change `x_csr.indptr` dtype doesn't change the calculation method.  Note also that after all this prep work, the actual multiplication is performed in compiled C code (`csr_matmat_pass1`, `csr_matmat_pass2`).

Comment: the goal is to use less memory without making the calculation too slow or incorrect. hmm. i didn't notice dot changes the indptr from uint32 to int32. when the computer does the dot, scipy uses lots of memory.

Comment: A `uint32` uses the same memory as a `int32`.

Comment: i worry that some value in the indptr array can overflow or wrap around. Like 256 goes back to 0 in uint8. So far the dot operation takes roughly the same amount of time and memory when i use uint32 or int32 in the original csr matrix.

Comment: Digging into the multiplication code I find that it makes its own choices regarding the index dtype - for the inputs as well as the output.  And it choose between `int32` and `int64`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was reading the source of the dot function of csr_matrix. That makes things more clear.

Comment: +1 "It doesn't try to make a view of the originals." Try `A[randomboolvec] *= -1` with `A` random sparse 100k x 60k, av 8 nnz/row, and watch mem in Mac Activity\ Monitor or the like: 